# UPSERT in Memsql from another table

Tags: insert, upsert, singlestore

I am trying this query to insert some records from a table to another one,when recods are not already exsiting in the target table, but I am getting the following error, what is the best query to UPSERT in memsql from another table?

Query:
INSERT INTO ema.device_set
  (segment_0, segment_1, segment_2, segment_3, segment_4, last_updated)
  SELECT tmp.segment_0, tmp.segment_1, tmp.segment_2, tmp.segment_3, tmp.segment_4, tmp.last_updated
  FROM ema.tmp_device_set tmp
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT  *
                       FROM    ema.device_set tab
                       WHERE   tmp.segment_0 = tab.segment_0 and tmp.segment_1 = tab.segment_1 and tmp.segment_2 = tab.segment_2 and tmp.segment_3 = tab.segment_3 and tmp.segment_4 = tab.segment_4
                     );

error: 
Partition has no master instance or Leaf Error: The database will be available to query in 2 seconds after recovery from disk is finished.

Answer (score 0):

That error message means your nodes are down or recovering from disk. It has nothing to do with the specific UPSERT you are trying to do.

Comment: seems query causes this error, cause we restart the cluster, and it crashes each time I tried the query

Comment: In that case, check the tracelog to find more information about why it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your query is not in any violations of the MemSQL INSERT...SELECT rules shown at the following link.

https://docs.memsql.com/docs/insert